# Tcpdf showing TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file

Tags: php, tcpdf

This is the first time i am looking into **TCPDF**. It was developed by previous developer. Now we have changed the server. And it is showing the following Error.

> TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file: /var/www/html/tcpdf/pdf_generate/pdf_ca/ado131822-2017-11-09060853.pdf

Please Help me and Guide me with the possibility of what can cause this error. for temporarily basses i have kept the permission to **777** but even that doesn't helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that file **ado131822-2017-11-09060853.pdf** is not open anywhere when you run script. if it's open somewhere else then TCPDF can't open it.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your folder doesn't have proper permissions. Change your directory permissions. In Linux, you will do this like mentioned below.

```
chmod -R 0777 /var/www/html/tcpdf/pdf_generate/pdf_ca/
```

If the above one not working then try to use the below code before your pdf output

```
ob_clean();
```